# Получение xml с сервера методом GET

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь получить xml с сайта, чтобы отпарсить его, но почему-то метод doInBackground возвращает мне null.

Раньше использовал этот же код, и все работало, а сейчас почему-то нет. Может, дело в том, что раньше все было в одном файле, а теперь нет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
package classes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * Created by Mikhail on 28.03.2015.
 */
public class GetXMLFromServer {

    InputStreamReader reader;

    public GetXMLFromServer(){
        //reader = null;
    }

    public InputStreamReader getReaderWithXML(String url){

        GetXMlTask task = new GetXMlTask(url);
        task.execute(url);

        return reader;
    }

    public void setReader(InputStreamReader newReader){
        this.reader = newReader;
    }

    class GetXMlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, InputStreamReader>{

        String url;

        public GetXMlTask(String url){
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected InputStreamReader doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStreamReader iStream = null;
            try {
                iStream = new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(params[0]));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return iStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader) {
            super.onPostExecute(inputStreamReader);
            setReader(inputStreamReader);
        }

        public InputStream getUrlData(String urlString) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
            return res.getEntity().getContent();
        }
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на приложение](https://github.com/mrabaev48/Currency)

Comment: ну, дебажьте... ставьте брейкпоинты, и вперед. Кроме того, e.printStackTrace(); должен вывести ошибки, если такие есть. Вы в логкат смотрели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы допустили несколько ошибок.

1. В методе ShowCurrencyActivity.onCreate не нужно делать тяжелую
   работу по выкачиванию и парсингу XML.
2. Скорее всего getXML.getReaderWithXML(euBankUrl) вернет null, потому
   что этот метод инициализирует асинхронное скачивание урла. И это
   протяженный во времени процесс. Нельзя делать предположение о том,
   что итоговый InputStream уже готов.
3. Почему бы парсинг не делать там-же, где делаете скачивание?

Предлагаю сделать так:
ShowCurrencyActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_currency);

    loadViews();

    list = new ArrayList();

    GetXMLFromServer getXML = new GetXMLFromServer(curList);
    InputStreamReader reader = getXML.getReaderWithXML(euBankUrl);
    //XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(reader);
    //list = parser.ecbParse();

    //curList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ShowCurrencyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
}
```

И далее в GetXMLFromServer.java

```
package classes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Mikhail on 28.03.2015.
 */
public class GetXMLFromServer {

private final ListView mListView;
InputStreamReader reader;

public GetXMLFromServer(ListView listView){
    mListView = listView;
}

public InputStreamReader getReaderWithXML(String url){

    GetXMlTask task = new GetXMlTask(url);
    task.execute(url);

    return reader;
}

public void setReader(InputStreamReader newReader){
    this.reader = newReader;
}


class GetXMlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList>{

    String url;

    public GetXMlTask(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList list = null;
        try {
            InputStreamReader iStream = new InputStreamReader(getUrlData(params[0]));
            setReader(iStream);
            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(iStream);
            list = parser.ecbParse();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList list) {
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mListView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    }

    public InputStream getUrlData(String urlString) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet method = new HttpGet(urlString);
        HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
        return res.getEntity().getContent();
    }
}
```

}

Список валют получить удалось.
Удачи!

Comment: Уже давно нашел решение.
https://github.com/mrabaev48/CurrencyVer3/tree/master/CurrencyVer3/app/src/main/java

Comment: Но все равно спасибо)